# c# / oracle: open/close connection

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

I need help with database connections and my winapp.

I have a windows app (C#) that, after I log in, starts running 5 or 6 different queries in Oracle database, every 5-10 seconds. Application is up 24/7.

What is a proper way to do this?
Should I open connection during login and never close it until I close the app, or should I open and close connection every time I run a query?
For example:

```
//first query
conn.Open();
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds1, "Result1");
conn.Dispose();

return ds1;
```

---

```
//second query    
conn.Open();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds2, "Result2");
conn.Dispose();

return ds2;
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you able to tell us if connection pooling is turned on or not. This will determine the final solution.

Comment: it's enabled - default setting in ODT I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle OleDB provider you use in your application implements pooling. So, when you create and clore a connection, you only take/release a connection from a pool of 'real connection'.

This makes creating and disposing Connection objects a really cheap operation. If I were you, I would open a connection, execute my batch of queries, and close+dispose that connection as soon as I'm done and going to sleep (even for a few seconds).

Comment: Only if you have it turned on, though. I don't believe it is by default

Comment: Which should be, unless you have a good reason for not doing so. He didn't mention that.

Comment: this is what I'll go with. I implemented using block too, so I don't have to worry about conn.open / conn.dispose...

Answer (score 2):

Another option, of course is to have a single connection for each 'batch' of queries

However, if you're hitting the database that often then it sounds like you need a permanent connection for the duration of the application.

I asuume of course your sample was just by example, and you are not actaully hitting the database with raw SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `using` block in order to `clean` your `non managed object`

```
using(var connection = new OracleConnection("..."))
{
 .....

}
```

Nota : Using execute dispose on your object in the end of treatment

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: yep I can implement using block, but, correct me if I'm wrong, that's gonna open and close connection every time. The question is, how smart is that if I do it every few seconds?

Comment: @Alex you create connection object and you clean in the end of your query, in order to optimize your management of connection pool